# Refactored Android AlertDialogBuilder code to another class, style of the dialog breaks

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I created two fairly long functions which create an AlertDialogBuilder which builds an AlertDialog which is populated and launched. The alert dialogs produced are fairly large for dialogs, so a lot of views need to be populated within the dialog. For the sake of cleanliness, testability, SRP etc. I decided to move these functions into a new class.

Originally the functions were placed directly in the Activity class, and the alert dialogs launched fine. I've now moved both to an AlertDialogLauncher class, which takes an Activity parameter when launched, most of the original code is the same, I've got the alert dialog working, but the colours of the text and background colours of some of my views are off.

So the dialog is launching fine, just with incorrect colours, so I imagine it is loading an incorrect style or something similar?

Code...

**Original version (shortened)**

```
private void addNormalRow(final ScannedWiFiNetwork network) {
    TableRow row = (TableRow) View.inflate(this, R.layout.regular_network_table_row, null);

    // loads of code  

    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchNewNetworkDialog(network);
        }
    });
}


private void launchPreferredNetworkDialog(final ScannedWiFiNetwork network) {
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Connect to "+network.getSsid()+"?")
            .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.preferred_network_dialog,null))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show();


    final EditText passwordInput = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password);
    TextView passwordText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_password);

  //loads of code
}
```

Essentially, the launch dialog function is called and creates a new AlertDialog by passing the AlertDialog.Builder a reference to this (the Java class for my activity).

**Refactored Activity/Interface class**

```
  private void addNormalRow(final ScannedWiFiNetwork network) {
    TableRow row = (TableRow) View.inflate(this, R.layout.regular_network_table_row, null);

    //loads of code 

    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Activity activity = (Activity) v.getContext();
            dialogs.launchNewNetworkDialog(network, activity);
        }
    });
}
```

**New AlertDialogLauncher class**

```
public void launchPreferredNetworkDialog(final ScannedWiFiNetwork network, final Activity activity) {

    Context con = activity.getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);

    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setTitle("Connect to "+network.getSsid()+"?")
            .setView((layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.preferred_network_dialog,null)))
            .setCancelable(false)
    .show();
```

As you can see, in this new class an Activity must be passed in to be used to create the layout inflater and context objects used later on to populate the views. All this works fine, however as mentioned earlier, the text colours change and the background of the buttons.

I'm loading the same xml layout file, so I'd assume it is loading an incorrect or default style somehow when I provide it with a default activity object (retrieved from calling getContext on the button view added to the dialog).

I've tried replacing 'activity' with NetworkListActivity.this (my activity name), that compiles but gives me the same ruined style outcome.

Thanks in advance for any help. Hope the question is clear!

Comment: Have you tried inflating your content view against the dialog builder's theme? So use `dialog.setView(LayoutInflater.from(dialog.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.preferred_network_dialog, null))`. Or if you're targeting API 21+, just use `dialog.setView(R.layout.preferred_network_dialog)`.

Comment: Can't seem to do that. The setView line is inlined with the Builder constructor, that line contains a reference to dialog, but since the object hasn't been built I can't use it. I've tried to call it seperately but I can't call it afterwards because I call show() at the end of the constructor, and I can't call setView and then show once again later on, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been dialogBuilder.setView() and dialogBuilder.getContext(). Make a separate variable for the builder, break up the builder call chain, and make the show() call on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem.. I never applied a style to my dialog xml layout file, some of the text views which I did not assign explicit text colors two are defaulting to the style of the dialog, I found this out when experimenting with changing the style which can be done by adding R.style.STYLE_NAME to the AlertDialogBuilder constructor (after the 'activity' parameter).

So yeah, I just didn't apply a style and need to be careful with views I haven't applied a style to!